# isolated storage explorer in mango update for WP7

Tags: windows-phone

i read about the isolated storage explorer in the mango update. but i cant find it in VS2010, can somebody tell me how to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about the official tool [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). It is located in `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool` (add (x86) to the Program Files path if you are running a 64-bit machine).

There is also an open-source tool available [here](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) that does a similar job.